# How to force ViewState restoration after child controls are recreated?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, viewstate

Consider I have 2 controls, `C` and `CompositeC` which contains `C`. Both `C` and `CompositeC` have ViewState.

Now consider a third control causes a postback.

The resulting life cycle will be as follow:

1. `CompositeC` tries to restore state. To do so it needs to create the child controls, so it creates `C`.
2. When `C` is created it's ViewState is restored.
3. The third control's postback event is triggered. At this time a handler calls `CompositeC.RecreatedChildControls()` and `C` is created again.
4. Everything renders.

The problem is that `C` state is not restored again after step 3. `RecreateChildControls` method should modify the control's state so that when `C` is reintroduced to the `CompositeC` control's collection it's viewstate is automatically restored but it doesn't.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found this is by design and it makes sense. ViewState is meant to allow for state restoration after a postback. If after that I recreate my controls, it won't take place.